# Cut string in Python from specific word/words to the end of the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to remove part of a string from specific expression. For example:

```
string = "Hello my name is John and I would like to eat pizza"
string.removeTillTheEnd(string, "John")
```

now string will be `Hello my name is`

replace function is not enough...

Comment: With regex it would be [`John.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/e6PtBe/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex or splitting into a list, just *find* the position and *slice*:

```
string = "Hello my name is John and I would like to eat pizza"
string = string[:string.find('John')].strip()
print(string)   # "Hello my name is"
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```py
string = "Hello my name is John and I would like to eat pizza"
split_string = string.split("John", maxsplit=1)[0]
```

The [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method on strings splits a string into a list given a seperator, and we take the first element that is found. The `maxsplit` argument is used to only seperate the first occurrence of "John" that it finds.